# Adding filename to column header in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which i created from merging one column from 7 different excel file. Below is the code i used:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

my_excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\.........\*.xlsx")

total_dataframe = pd.DataFrame() 

for file in my_excel_files:
    new_df = df['Comments']
    total_dataframe = pd.concat([total_dataframe, new_df], axis=1) # Puts together all Comments columns
```

As you can see from the code i grab the 'Comments' column from each excel and put them together into a new df, the only issue is i want to be able to add the filename into the column name so i know which column comes from which excel file, all of them are just called 'Comments' right now. So ideally one of the column headers would be 'Comments (first_response.xlsx)'

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `pathlib` and `pd.concat`.

Using a dict comprehension we can grab the `.name` attribute from the pathlib object and when using `concat` the filename will be set as the index:

```
from pathlib import Path

dfs = pd.concat({f.name : pd.read_excel(f) for f in Path(r'C:\Users\..').glob('*.xlsx')})
```

This will create an index with the file name, you can `reset_index` if you want to place it as a column.